# Disable submit button in the html form if the input is incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, forms, error-checking

So, the main thing is the field

```
 function displaySubmit(hdd, answer) {

            document.getElementById(answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(hdd + 'Answer').style.display = "block";
            if (!((answer == "yes" && hdd == "Hard Disk Drive") || answer == "no")) {
                $('f1').submit(function () {
                    $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
                });
            }
        }
```

I want to unable submit button only if the answer (input) is "Hard Disk Drive". So, the condition for submit button to be unabled is if the answer on  question "Are you a lady?" is "Yes" and the answer on the question about HDD is "Hard Disk Drive" or if the answer on  question "Are you a lady?" is "No".

I've tried to write a javascript function for this, but am not sure whether I've put the right commands for disabling the button. Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shit2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="aleksei.jpg" />
    <script>
        function displayQuestion(answer) {

            document.getElementById(answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";

            if (answer == "yes") { // hide the div that is not selected

                document.getElementById('noQuestion').style.display = "none";

            } else if (answer == "no") {

                document.getElementById('yesQuestion').style.display = "none";

            }

        }
        function displaySubmit(hdd, answer) {

            document.getElementById(answer + 'Question').style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById(hdd + 'Answer').style.display = "block";
            if (!((answer == "yes" && hdd == "Hard Disk Drive") || answer == "no")) {
                $('f1').submit(function () {
                    $(this).find(':input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   
    <br />
    <form id="f1" action="file:///C:/Users/home/Documents/website1/submit.html?">
        
        <p class="areyoualady"> Are you a lady?</p>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" id="yes" name="yesOrNo" value="yes" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />Yes
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" id="no" name="yesOrNo" value="no" onchange="displayQuestion(this.value)" />No
        </label>

        <div id="yesQuestion" style="display:none;">
            <br />
            What is the full name of HDD?
            <input type="text" id="Hdd" placeholder="Hard Dick Drive" required />
        </div>

        <div id="noQuestion" style="display:none;">
            <br />
            <p>Only ladies are asked questions :)</p>
        </div>
        </br>

        <input type="submit" href='file:///C:/Users/home/Documents/website1/submit.html?' />

    </form>

</body>
```

P.S. Don't pay attention to the content, it's just to make fun of my lecturer

Comment: This is not how forms should work. You can control what values are to be deemed invalid in your form by using `pattern` attribute which will work fine for values like "Hard Disk Drive", or you can use `setCustomValidity` method. Both of these will make the form non-submittable if needed. Don't muck about with Submit button `disabled` state if you can avoid it -- your use case is trivial enough you don't have to. `pattern`, `required` and `setCustomValidity` are designed for cases like yours. You don't need to reinvent form submission wheel like most people seem to do.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just got frustrated by the conditions

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic solution to problems like you have demonstrated -- where the form shouldn't submit unless an input value conforms to a specific pattern including being a specific text string, is to use a combination of `required`, `pattern` and/or `setCustomValidity` properties alone:

```
<form>
    <input name="hdd" pattern="Hard Disk Drive" required />
</form>
```

The form defined above won't be submittable unless the value of the `input` element named "hdd" is "Hard Disk Drive".

However, `pattern` wasn't arguably designed to flag invalid *values* verbatim necessarily, it's more to define well, *patterns* of valid values.

I'd use `setCustomValidity` instead:

```
<form>
    <input name="hdd" required />
    <script>
        (function setup_hdd_input(hdd_input) {
            hdd_input.addEventListener("change", ev => {
                ev.target.setCustomValidity((ev.target.value == "Hard Disk Drive") ? "" : "The value is expected to be 'Hard Disk Drive'");
            });
        })(document.currentScript.previousElementSibling);
    </script>
</form>
```

In the above, whenever the value of the input field is changed, `setCustomValidity` is called with an empty string (which communicates to the user agent that the value "valid") or a custom error message string (which communicates that the value is "invalid" and will be displayed by the user agent next to the input field if the [now invalid] form is attempted submitted).